# Simplifying the function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, numerical-linear-algebra

Identify for which values of $x$ there is subtraction of nearly equal numbers, and find an alternate form that avoids the problem:
$$E = \frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{1}{1-x} = -\frac{2x}{1-x^2} = \frac{2x}{x^2-1} $$
How come $-2x/(1-x^2)$ can be changed to $2x(x^2 - 1)$ according to the homework solutions? Why does the denominator change it's digits/variables places? Shouldn't it be just $2x/(1-x^2)$ ? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you put in some number for $x$, like, say, $x=2$, and see what happens?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I don't get your point

Comment: the -2x can't just magically change into a positive 2x.  But a/b = (-a)/(-b) so if you change the sign of the -2x to 2x, you must also change the sign of (1 - x^2) to -(1 - x^2).  But switching the order changes the parity.  -(1-x^2) = (x^2 - 1).  So $\frac {-2x}{1-x^2} = \frac {2x}{-(1-x^2)} = \frac{2x}{x^2 - 1}$

Comment: You want to know why $-2x/(1-x^2)$ doesn't become $2x/(1-x^2)$ instead of $2x/(x^2-1)$, right? So put $x=1/2$ in each of the three expressions, and see which ones are equal and which ones aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for numbers $a,b$ and $c$, we may write
$$
\frac a{b-c}=\frac a{-1(c-b)}=\frac 1{-1} \cdot \frac a{c-b}=\frac {-1}{1} \cdot \frac a{c-b}=\frac{-a}{c-b}.
$$

In your case, we have $a=-2x$, $b=1$, and $c=x^2$. So,
$$
\frac{-2x}{1-x^2}=\frac{-2x}{-1(x^2-1)}=\frac 1{-1}\cdot \frac{-2x}{x^2-1}=\frac {-1}1\cdot \frac{-2x}{x^2-1}=\frac{2x}{x^2-1}.
$$

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$
$$\frac{-2x}{1-x^2}=\frac{-1\times2x}{-1\times(-1+x^2)}$$
$$=\frac{\cancel{-1\times}2x}{\cancel{-1\times}(-1+x^2)}$$
$$=\frac{2x}{x^2-1}$$